# Add confirmation popup on place order button

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I wants to add confirmation popup when user click on place order.
How can i put that?

is it possible to go with editing `function.php`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins available that can do this for you. For example [YITH WooCommerce Added to Cart Popup](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-added-to-cart-popup/).

Otherwise, I would recommend you to [create a custom plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) that adds this functionality with Javascript. Or add it to your theme. If is not a custom theme, then take a look at [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: can you give me code?

Comment: @KetanKpBorada Just use the plugin I posted. I can not give you a usable piece of code since it depends on your theme